# How to rewrite the query without NOT equal to, NOT IN?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an query written with NOT IN and <>.
Due to NOT IN and Not equal operator it took lot of cost.
Below is the query

```
SELECT NVL (SUM (NVL (I.AMOUNT, 0)), 0)
FROM Start_tb C,
  End_tb I
WHERE C.Start_key             = :B3
AND I.End_key                 = C.End_key
AND I.Com_number              <> :B2
AND NVL (I.Process_typ, 'NA') = 'H'
AND NVL (I.Code, 'Elp_01')    = :B1
AND I.Typ_id                NOT IN (3, 4);
```

Below is the explain plan details

```
Plan hash value: 34574793
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                         |       |       |  3648 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                 |                         |     1 |    49 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                  |                         |     1 |    49 |  3648   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                 |                         |     1 |    49 |  3648   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN| Index_clm               |     1 |    13 |  3646   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | Index_range             |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | End_tb                  |     1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can i able to rewrite this query to increase performance?

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I missed to include that am used join syntax too. But it wont reduce cost..

Comment: . . I for one hardly bother reading queries that use commas.  They are archaic.

Comment: Please post your explain plan with `filter` and `outline` sections

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If you are unable to provide the explain plan details Sayan suggested, at least [edit] your question to also include number of rows on each table, and indexes' details.

Answer (score 0):

can the last line not be like this :
AND I.type != 3 AND I.type != 4
Then you are not using "not in"